# Don't show drop down box when click outside box

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an issue I made a directive which hidding my box when I click outside a box. But it also works in the other side. That means when box is hidden and I clicked somewhere it showing my box. I can't solve it.. Any ideas what is wrong?

HTML:
    **The problem was that input box was outside the emClickOutsideSearchBox Directive**

```
<div emClickOutsideSearchBox (clickOutsideSearchBox)="hideBoxMainSearch()" >
                  <input type="search" class="main-search width-searcher" (click)="toggleDropDown()" placeholder="Search..." formControlName="query" name="query" />
         <div *ngIf='showDropDown' class="state-container-dropdown">
          <div *ngFor="let event of events">
             <div class="founded-event">
                   <p>{{event.name}}</p>
             </div>
         </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

TypeScript:

```
showDropDown = false;



  toggleDropDown() {
  this.showDropDown = true;

}
hideBoxMainSearch() {
  if(this.showDropDown == true){
  this.showDropDown = !this.showDropDown;
}
}
```

Directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[emClickOutsideSearchBox]'
})
export class ClickOutsideSearchBoxDirective {

    @Output() public clickOutsideSearchBox = new EventEmitter();
    constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef) { }

    @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
    public onClick(targetElement) {
        if (!targetElement) {
            return;
        }
        const isClickedInside = this._elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
        if (!isClickedInside) {
            this.clickOutsideSearchBox.emit(null);
        }
    }

  }
```

Comment: Idea: when your dropdown becomes open, add a class to it let say `.is-open` and when you click in side check if dropdown has class `.is-open` or not. If has it close the dropdown o/w do nothing.

Comment: Why don't you switch the logic of both functions toggleDropDown and hideBoxMainSearch?

Comment: @ColinCline but where I have to check this? Where should be `.is-open` class?

Comment: Unfortunately i am not good at `typescipt` but that was an idea. you can use variables too, if dropdown is open set `true` to a variable while initially it was `false` and on side click check if it is (variable) `true` or `false` so with this approach you'll prevent dropdown from opening by side click when you just sat variable to `true` just in dropdown function.